# What is the algorithm to handle large arrays in NoSQL databases

Tags: database-design, nosql, database

I just want to know how NoSQL databases store very large arrays/hashtables then search them easily. Do they chunk it, or what? I want to know how it handles all those keys with good performance; what is the algorithm?

Comment: In at least some cases, [B-tree indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: thanxxx to your fast response i'll see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all very different, so NoSQL databases can use a variety of algorithms, data structures, and strategies based on the nature of the data, whether updates are permitted (vs. new inserts with later timestamps) and so on.

But if you want to do some research, look into these:

- B-trees and B+-trees
- Bloom Filters
- Bulk load
- Pre-splitting
- Partitioning
- Secondary indexes
- Data locality
- Compaction

Good luck with your research!

Answer (score 0):

On the example of Couchbase (this is one of the fastest DB) I can say, that CB uses a very efficient algorithm of sharding ("vBucket" in terms of CB). The second ingredient of efficiency of Couchbase operations that is documents in CB stored "in-memory" with persisting to disk, which greatly increases perfomance of operations.